# How do you run a test suite from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, test-suite

How do you execute and get the results for a test suite from Visual Studio Code?

Currently, whenever I want to run one, I have to go into the org, and then log into the developer console. It works, but it is inefficient.

Comment: What is *"org"*? Is it *"organisation*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there's a GUI option for this (yet?), but you can always just open a Terminal and type in:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -s "SuiteName" -c --json
```

Or, you could add it as an npm script in package.json and use the "npm: run task" menu option.

For example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "run-package-tests": "sfdx force:apex:test:run -s 'SuiteName' -c --json"
  }
}
```

Comment: That works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SFDX supports the command:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run --targetusername thealias
```

I would think that you can run this within VSCode (though I don't use VSCode so can't be 100% sure). Check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm) for other options.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long time since this question asked but I have got something to share, you can use this vscode [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AyuSharma-dev.salesforce-testsuite-manager):

It will provide many other features also like creating a Test Suite, Running Test Suite and you can also retrieve your test suites easily.

Answer (score 0):

As of SFDX 7.121.8 and VsCode 1.61.2, the following commands are available from the Command Palette in VsCode:

```
SFDX:Run Apex Test Suite
SFDX:Create Test Suite
SFDX:Add Tests to Apex Test Suite
```